# labelsep in enumitem: stretch ignored

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumitem, description

As the title says: `labelsep` setting in the `enumitem` package ignores the stretch part. I would be happy to have a stretch there (in the end actually the current font's interword stretch achieved by `\fontdimen2\font plus 5em minus\fontdimen4\font`).

See the MWE (the value `0pt plus 400pt` is of course extreme, but it nicely shows what happes):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textwidth=4cm,textheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newskip\mydescskip
\mydescskip0pt plus 400pt

% TRY EITHER ONE OF THESE TWO OPTIONS
\setlist[description]{labelsep=\mydescskip, leftmargin=0pt}
%\setlist[description]{labelsep=0pt plus 400pt, leftmargin=0pt}

\begin{document}

\texttt{REAL OUTPUT:}

\begin{description}
\item[X]
AAA\hspace{\mydescskip}BBB xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{description}

\texttt{DESIRED OUTPUT:}

\noindent\textbf{X}\hspace{\mydescskip}%
AAA\hspace{\mydescskip}BBB xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

\end{document}
```

Since it is a part of a class, the solution must be as clean as possible (and surely mustn't require any change in UI).

Comment: it sets latex's `\labelsep` register but that is a dimen not a skip, so allowing stretch there would take you deep into latex list internals. might be easier to patch item add an additional skip after the \item (no time now:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `\labelsep` is a `\dimen` and LaTeX uses it as such, so no matter how much stretch you specify it will be ignored. Probably the best is to change the meaning of `\item` so that it adds the skip after it; this shouldn't be a problem as you don't `\label` description items.

```
\setlist[description]{
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelsep=0pt,
  before=\let\item\descitem,
}

\let\oriitem\item
\newcommand\descitem[1][]{\oriitem[#1]\hspace{\mydescskip}\ignorespaces}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

I don't think it's a good idea to have a stretchable labelsep, though.

Comment: ad "not a good idea": It is IMHO useful for description where all the spaces in `\item[...]` and all the spaces in the latter text are stretchable. The space after `\item` is there quite naturally an interword (or an interseqence) space.